# Count Nulls on multiple columns

Tags: hadoop, hive

So I'm trying to write Data Quality rules in a Hive environment- counting the number of nulls(depending on the table, there could be many nulls) in multiple schemas and tables. I am trying to do this in the most efficient way possible. My goal is to put the least amount of resource use on the production servers, and return the results as quickly as possible- after the results are returned, I'd run additional calculations in an Excel or Microsoft PowerBI environment to communicate the results in an easy to understand report with visuals.

I've tried doing the following;

```
SELECT
COUNT (firstName),
COUNT (lastName),
COUNT (state)
FROM
`ordertable`.customerinfo
where businessday = '2023-03-08'
```

I get a long error message along the lines of "ODBC Database Error: [MapR][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '1' error message: 'org.apache.hive.service.di.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask...

The output that I'd LIKE to get, is:

| column | null count |
| --- | --- |
| firstName | 0 |
| lastName | 0 |
| state | 10000 |

I've searched another related thread here titled "Select columns with only NULL values : HIVE", but the 'answer' seems to be a query that only returns true if columns contain not nulls.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you get any query to work here? Does the query work if you only count one column at once?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Counting once at a time works with "is null" only